# Need clarification- Can we build CI CD pipeline using Jenkins where my development code written is in C# and automation code is java eclipse

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, jenkins, github, continuous-integration

Need clarification- Can we build CI CD pipeline using Jenkins where my development code written is in C# and automation code is java eclipse

**Requirement :**
1. Whenever developer will commit the code then new Build should be generated 
2. It should run unit test and smoke suite 
3. Once Testing smoke suite passed it should show build passed else build should be failed

Can we achieve it using Jenkins. I have concerns like my development and automation code in two different language. In order to build pipeline do we need to have dev and test code in the same repository

Thanks in advance . Please suggests me

I am in exploration phase.

I need help in configuration. I don't think any code will require for this.

Comment: Even if there is no Jenkins plugin for it, if you can run it from the command line and the exit code indicates the result, you can also run it in Jenkins. Yes, the test and main code to run can be split into several repositories.

Comment: Thanks, Do you have any link where we are generating dev build on code commit in GIT and also triggering automation of java code

Comment: Using a `Jenkinsfile` (instead of the web UI) to specify a Jenkins job, looking for new commits (and run the job if there are any) every three minutes is `pipeline { ... triggers { pollSCM 'H/3 * * * *' } ...}`. If the documentation on https://jenkins.io/ is not sufficient, you will find many examples and explanations on the web.